# How to find if electron app is in foreground?

Tags: electron

I have a requirement where I want to perform an action inside the electron app only when it is in foreground.

It is an electron-react application. On mounting of a component, I want to schedule a periodic task which only runs when the app is in focus or is being used by the user. And pause the task when the app goes in background.

How can we detect the Electron app being in foreground?

Comment: `BrowserWindow` has a method called `isFocused()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`isFocused` method from `BrowserWindow`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winisfocused). To get your own BrowserWindow, you can do this :

```
remote.BrowserWindow.getAllWindows();
```

This will return all your app's windows. So to get the first / primary window, you could deconstruct the array like this :

```
const [yourBrowserWindow] = remote.BrowserWindow.getAllWindows();
console.log(yourBrowserWindow.isFocused());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [focus](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-focus) / [blur](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-blur) events on your BrowserWindow to be notified when the app is focused / unfocused.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({})

mainWindow.on('focus', () => {
    console.log('window got focus')
})

mainWindow.on('blur', () => {
    console.log('window blur')
})
```

You may want to update the component's state within these event handlers or use any other method to keep track of the current focus status.

This assumes that you have a single application window. If you have multiple, you'll need to extend the check to cover all of your windows.

Comment: This can be unstable because the window can be foreground and stay foreground while the blur event fires. For example pressing TAB does this.